# Resolving a conflict of git

Tags: git, github

How can I solve this conflict? 
I forgot to do 'git pull origin master', so I get this conflict. How I can solve it and with which commands ?

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
app.use('/ss/arabic', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
app.use('/ss/english', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));

=======
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.redirect('/arabic');
});

app.use('/arabic', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
app.use('/english', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
>>>>>>> ceba0237b227d28795ce7f15d7ebddbe522ea4e2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to solve it manually now. Open that file in an editor and fix the conflicts by removing the parts of your code you don't want. All conflicts are marked by

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
[Current HEAD's code]
=======
[Code of the pulled commit]
>>>>>>> [The pulled commit's hash]
```

After you fixed all merge conflicts, you have to commit (and push) your changes. Then you're done.